# When and why Visual Studio creates the "x86" subfolder inside "bin" after build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with many projects, containing 3 executable projects. All of my projects are configured to target "x86" platform, in the solution configuration manager I've even deleted the others like "Mixed" and "Any CPU" (this is becuase I'm using some third party libraries which are restricting me to stick with x86). All 3 executable projects are simple WinForms applications built with C#, targetting .NET 4 full profile.

Now when I build one of my executable projects, its output is built in "bin/x86/Release" directory. When I build one other executable project, its output is built in "bin/Release", without the "x86" subfolder.

Why is this - at first glance - inconsistency?

UPDATE

I need to fix it because I'd like to run some scripts after succesful builds, and they will expect the output in a consistent folder structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to Project > Properties > Build in Visual Studio you will see your target platform (among other settings).

This folder is created if your build target is 32bit (X86), or 'Any CPU'

Finally, check your 'Output' Folder: Projects > Properties > Output Path

Comment: Thank you, but all of my three projects are set to x86 target platform, as I stated in my post.

Comment: Exactly? 32Bit IS x86.

Comment: Yes I know that, I only have one platform in all of these 3 projects, and that one is "x86". Still 2 of them builds to "bin/x86/Release", and one builds to "bin/Release".

Comment: Hm. I've just noticed the explicit Ouput folder option. It's an old project, and has been reconfigured several times, probably something went wrong and it's Output path stayed without the "x86" subdir. Thanks, I'm gonna accept your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Sorry about the wrong answer at first!