# Visual Studio - InstallShield setup in a project with System.Data.SQLite

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, installshield, system.data.sqlite, installshield-le

I have a C# class library that references [System.Data.SQLite (from nuget)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/). This is the structure of my bin folder after build:

> - MyProject.dll
> - System.Data.SQLite.dll
> - x86/SQLite.Interop.dll
> - x64/SQLite.Interop.dll

`System.Data.SQLite` needs the `SQLite.Interop` to run and the correct dll is found at run time. However, when I generate a setup with *InstallShield* that includes the project primary output, the x86 and x64 folders are not copied and my application fails to run.

There is any way to force *Visual Studio* to include x86 and x64 folders in the primary output?

There is any way to include the folders manually in the *InstallShield* with **relative** path?

> **My environment:**
>
> - Visual Studio 2012 Professional
> - Install Shield 2013 Limited Edition (Free)
> - System.Data.SQLite 1.0.96

Comment: Those sound like dependencies rather than primary output, but remember the output groups are for convenience rather than control. If you want full control of your setup, you're better off selecting the files statically.

Comment: Unfortunately, the x64 and x86 folders are managed by Nuget package, so the only way I found is to use an absolute path. It works, but each developer will have to configure in it in own computer. Would be great if I could use a relative path but I did not found how with the free edition.

Comment: @Rafael Just so you know. You can manually change in the setup.isl file from 
`c:\yourpath\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.94.0\build\net40\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll` to `&lt;ISProjectFolder&gt;..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.94.0\build\net40\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll`
(or where ever you have your SQLite.Interop located)

Comment: I hope you have tried the settings (Solution Explorer -> Right Click Project -> Properties -> Build) Target Platform as 64 bit or 32 bit instead Any CPU  to force x86 or x64.

Comment: Also check the output path. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940659/when-and-why-visual-studio-creates-the-x86-subfolder-inside-bin-after-build for more details

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to add/deploy folders through InstallShield. Under the Files tabs you can add the files/folder. While adding these files you can set relative path as well in this. Just set a property with the path and use that property in your relative path. So where do want to copy these files (reference locations for DLL), you can add that folder structure through InstallShield and you can add files in that.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across the same problem using VS2013 / Installshield LE; I ended up opting for changing the NuGet package on my machine to NOT create the x86 folder for the SQLite.interop.dll under the build folder.

To do that, look in the "packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.104.0\build" folder under your project directory. Then pick the subfolder pertinent to the version of .NET you're targeting, and open the "System.Data.SQLite.Core.targets" file in a text editor. You'll want to delete all references to "`%(RecursiveDir)`" EXCEPT in the "`SQLite Interop Library Content Items`" section. Save, clean, and rebuild - the interop dll should now be in the same folder as the main executable/etc, and Installshield should be able to automatically include it as a dependency.

If it doesn't show up in the right place, try editing a different .NET version's .target file until you hit the right one.